# Moving a block to center using css

Tags: css

I have a section in my rails web application's view page which is nothing but a code that's displaying the facebook like, twitter tweet and other sharing options. The code goes like this:-

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-50effbad1fc26ade"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

I wanted to move this div to center. So my css code for this is like:

```
 .center {
text-align: center;
}
```

And I then added the `<div class="center">` to my code...

But it's node moving everything center. What could be the reason??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You never told us where you added '<div class="center">'. Also look into jsfiddle.net

Comment: I have added the '<div class="center"> at the beginning of the above mentioned code and closed that at the end of the above code.

Comment: You'll need to show the css of the other classes in there. Likely there are some floats (or even absolutes). jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

try puting a value to the width of your .center! For your convenience you can use a background color to keep your eyes on different div s what difference it makes.

```
.center {
text-align: center;
width: 70%

/*For the sake of understanding divs sometimes background color helps*/
background-color:#b0e0e6;

}
```